# Reorder a list without ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

For reasons I won't go into, I'm not using ng-repeat for a list of items.

I have a list like this:

```
    <p>Search: <input type="text" ng-model="search"></p>

    <div id="grid" filter-list="search">

      <div id="item1" class="[list of properties]">
      //item content
      </div>
      <div id="item2" class="[list of properties]">
      //item content
      </div>

      <div id="item3" class="[list of properties]">
      //item content
      </div>

      <div id="item4" class="[list of properties]">
      //item content
      </div>

    </div>
```

As you can see I already have a search function working well.

My app script looks like this:

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {

    });



    app.directive('filterList', function ($timeout) {
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                var div = Array.prototype.slice.call(element[0].children);

                function filterBy(value) {
                    div.forEach(function (el) {
                        el.className = el.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ? '' : 'ng-hide';
                    });
                }

                scope.$watch(attrs.filterList, function (newVal, oldVal) {
                    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
                        filterBy(newVal);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });



</script>
```

The problem is I need to be able to reorder the list based on class values or even the ids (At this stage it doesn't matter).

Every tutorial/guide online assumes that the code uses "ng-repeat" ... which I simply can't use here.

Is there any way I can get the items to reorder without using ng-repeat?

Comment: Why not reverse engineer the dom elements attribute values, content etc back into data model and replace with `ng-repeat` at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ng-repeat` just sort the data.

$scope.items = $scope.items.sort(yourSortFn);

Comment: I don't have items in a JS array. that's the main issue and why I can't use ng-repeat.

Comment: Please provide more info about how your data is formatted so I can provide a better answer.

Comment: The info is exactly as I've put in the code in the question. :) It is a simple grid of divs.

Answer (score 0):

Sort or filter or reduce your array of elements any way you need then append the results

Very basic example using descending id:

```
scope.sortDesc = function() {
  div.sort(function(a, b) {
    return /\d+/.exec(b.id) - /\d+/.exec(a.id);
  });
  element.append(div);

}
scope.sortDesc();
```

[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/cQZbpWERMJa575JQnphQ?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this sorting script:

```
<ul id="id01">
  <li>Oslo</li>
  <li>Stockholm</li>
  <li>Helsinki</li>
  <li>Berlin</li>
  <li>Rome</li>
  <li>Madrid</li>
</ul>

<script>
function sortList() {
  var list, i, switching, b, shouldSwitch;
  list = document.getElementById("id01");
  switching = true;
  /* Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done: */
  while (switching) {
    // Start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    b = list.getElementsByTagName("LI");
    // Loop through all list items:
    for (i = 0; i < (b.length - 1); i++) {
      // Start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /* Check if the next item should
      switch place with the current item: */
      if (b[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b[i + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
        /* If next item is alphabetically lower than current item,
        mark as a switch and break the loop: */
        shouldSwitch= true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /* If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark the switch as done: */
      b[i].parentNode.insertBefore(b[i + 1], b[i]);
      switching = true;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Just target the div elements instead of li elements, and compare them based on their .className property (after formating them propelly depending on what data you get) instead of their .innerHTML